# how can i make the data got from a server stay on the appliction for a certain period of time?

Tags: android

Like the Gmail application on the android phone ,i want to make an application that gets data from the server  and that data remains on the application until the e data on the server is changed

any help rendered to me will be of great assistance 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your data somewhere on the device.

- [File](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
- [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
- [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Realm. it's faster than sqlite
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Please show an example how to set this up in a few lines as well